# getting records of last 30 mins from mysql database with unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I wanted to get data from table of a mysql database in which my timestamp is in unix format.

I used the following query after doing some research but still not able to get the results, it shows empty rows. Can anyone help:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM bs_items
 WHERE  owner_id='3'
 AND timestamp > (now() - interval 30 minute)
```

It should work don't know where is the problem:

```
TABLE: bs_items
==================================================
| log_id |  owner_id   |  item_code  | timestamp |
==================================================
| 1      | 10          | 100         | 12345     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2      | 12          | 200         | 23456     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while but I think this might be correct:

```
SELECT * FROM bs_items WHERE 
datetime_column < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Also you might be able to do it with a select to make the date time comparison via a select and place that within the query for the less than.
    select '2012-07-22 13:50:14' + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE

So at a guess:
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetimecol < (select '2012-07-22 13:50:14' + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)

Try run a query to see what the result is adding 30 mins to see result to debug:

```
select '2012-07-22 13:50:14' + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

Comment: no friend its giving me all the records and the timstamp is in unix format

Comment: Another idea... I think FROM_UNIXTIME() works... Try a query on the unix time + interval 30 minture to see result.
Something like select FROM_UNIXTIME('value from db') + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE

Comment: @Darcey Almost correct, the < should be a > as the DATE_SUB function returns NOW() minus 30 minutes ago, hence to view the data from the last 30 minutes in the datetime_column would be selecting data that is greater than 30 minutes ago. Just mentioning for others coming across this solution if you didn't spot the difference when testing.

Answer (score 1):

it seems after trying long enough i found i perfect solution

```
   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bs_items WHERE 
   owner_id='$loguser' AND timestamp > ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -600)
   order by timestamp desc");
```

it seems to give results i want, sharing it might help someone..